# What does the .subscribe() function do?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am coding an API with `Angular2` and `NodeJS`, I am implementing services for my ِAPI that is supposed to get a list of tasks and display it. Here is the task service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class TaskService{
  constructor(private http:Http){
    console.log('Task Service Initialized...');
  }
  getTasks(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/tasks')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

For my `getTask` function (correct me if I am wrong) the `.map()` function takes my response and formats it in an array of values.
Here is now, the task components that uses the task service:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {TaskService} from '../../services/task.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'tasks',
  templateUrl: 'tasks.component.html',
})
export class TasksComponent  {
  constructor(private taskService:TaskService){
    this.taskService.getTasks()
      .subscribe(tasks =>{
        console.log(tasks);
    })
  }
}
```

I would like to understand what this `.subscribe()` function does and I can't find any relevant information.

Comment: a good start: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The [`.subscribe()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html) function is similar to the `Promise.then()`, `.catch()` and `.finally()` methods in `jQuery`, but instead of dealing with `promise`s it deals with [`Observable`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html)s.

That means it will subscribe itself to the `observable` of interest (which is `getTasks()` in your case) and wait until it is `successful` and then execute the first passed callback function which in your case is:

```
tasks => {
    console.log(tasks);
}
```

If you want it to run some logic on error (similar to `.catch()`) or on complete (similar to`.finally()`) you can pass that logic to the `subscribe` as following:

```
observable.subscribe(
  value => somethingToDoOnlyOnSuccess(value),
  error => somethingToDoOnlyOnError(error),
  () => somethingToDoAlways()
);
```

More examples and details can be found [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Observable#subscribe)

Comment: So is it possible to write it this way : this.taskService.getTask(function(){console.log(tasks);}) // Also i would like to understand why do we use tasks => and not only console.log(tasks)

Comment: yes it is possible to use the `function` notation, but the advantage of using the `arrow` notation (the `=>`) is that it preserves the meaning of `this`, see this [article](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html)

Answer (score -4):

The main advantage of `subscribe` comparing to promise `then` - you can notify changes using `observer.next(data)` many times and your subscribers will react on each change.

```
new Observable(observer => observer.next(data));
```

So if you have several listeners to the same event - all of them will receive change event each time observer generate new data and will call `observer.next()`. It is very useful when you have data that can be changed frequently and you want single and predictable flow to notify your listeners.

Promise `then` allow you to wait your async operation once.